# TikZ-cd's arrow style=math font does not respect surrounding color

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd

I want to unify three things:

- `$\to$`,
- `\draw[->]` in usual Ti*k*Z picture, and
- `\ar` in Ti*k*Z-cd

So far the following code achieves that when the text is black on white.
But the arrow heads are in black even in the white on black context.

I wonder if there is any official fix.

(And please let me know if there are better ways to sync the three arrows,)

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,20pt]{beamer}
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=blue,fg=white}
    \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}

\usepackage{mathtools,unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction*{axis_height}0{\begingroup\pgfmathreturn.25em\endgroup}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction*{rule_thickness}0{\begingroup\pgfmathreturn.06em\endgroup}
    \tikzset{
        every picture/.style={line width=rule_thickness},
        >/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=rightarrow,glyph length=.32em]},
        >>/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=twoheadrightarrow,glyph length=.49em]},
        c/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=hookleftarrow, swap,glyph length=.28em]},
    }
    \tikzcdset{
        every arrow/.style={/tikz/draw,->},
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    $A\to B$
    
    \tikz\draw[->](0,0)node(A){$A$}(2,0)node(B){$B$}(A)--(B);
    
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A\rar   &   B\rar[c->>] &   C
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but `\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=white}` seems to work. I didn't read but this issue seems related https://github.com/astoff/tikz-cd/issues/5.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot confirm immediately that is related but it does seem like there are too many things competing for `\everymath`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why exactly the arrow tip declaration does not apply the current color. It might have something to do with the fact that `tikz-cd` uses `\pgftext` to render the arrow tip, which is processed in a separate box/group that may be outside the scope of the color declarations - but maybe it's something different entirely. In any case it is not caused by `beamer`, I tested with `article` and that shows the same issue.

A workaround is to put the current color explicitly in the declaration of `glyph math command` using `\color{.}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,20pt]{beamer}
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=blue,fg=white}
    \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}

\usepackage{mathtools,unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}

\makeatletter
% copied from tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/arrow keys}{
  glyph math command/.code={% if csname #1 is undefined, we want it to remain so
    \pgfarrowsaddtooptions{\def\tikzcd@glyph{\color{.}$\begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\csname #1\endcsname$}}}}
\makeatother

    \pgfmathdeclarefunction*{axis_height}0{\begingroup\pgfmathreturn.25em\endgroup}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction*{rule_thickness}0{\begingroup\pgfmathreturn.06em\endgroup}
    \tikzset{
        every picture/.style={line width=rule_thickness},
        >/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=rightarrow,glyph length=.32em]},
        >>/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=twoheadrightarrow,glyph length=.49em]},
        c/.tip={Glyph[glyph math command=hookleftarrow, swap,glyph length=.28em]},
    }
    \tikzcdset{
        every arrow/.style={/tikz/draw,->},
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    $A\to B$
    
    \tikz\draw[->](0,0)node(A){$A$}(2,0)node(B){$B$}(A)--(B);
    
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A\rar   &   B\rar[c->>] &   C
    \end{tikzcd}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I guess this is the least complex solution for now. Thanks.

Comment: Let me add (because it took me some time to figure out) that @Marijn's answer works in general to fix the problem with `arrow style=math font`. One just needs (1) to add to add (only) the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, (2) to write `\tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}` *after*.